# Método está executando 3 vezes

Tags: java, java-8

Eu criei esse método para uma validação quando o usuário vai digitar a opção que aparece na tela:

```
private int menu;
private int menuImprimir;

public int getMenu() 
    {
        return menu;
    }
    public void ativarStatus() 
    {
        this.status = "Ativado";
    }

   public void menuImprimir() 
    {
        System.out.println("Deseja Imprimir os dados?" +
                "\n1 - Sim" + 
                "\n2 - Não");       
                this.menuImprimir = input.nextInt(); 

                while(this.menuImprimir < 1 || this.menuImprimir > 2) 
                {
                    System.out.println("\nErro! - Digite uma opção válida");

                    menuImprimir();
                }

                switch(this.menuImprimir) 
                {
                case 1:
                    imprimir();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Obrigado! ... ");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Opção inválida!\nDigite novamente: ");
                    break;
                }
    }
```

Se o cliente digitar a opção diferente de 0 e 1 ele fica dentro do while pedindo que ele digite a opção correta. Mas se o cliente digitar 3 vezes a opção errada e na quarta ele digitar a correta o sistema está imprimindo  `System.out.println("Concluído com Sucesso!");`"3 vezes para depois sair do método, mesmo eu colocando esse return..

Comment: Por favor, forneça um código que seja um **[mcve]** para que seja possível testar.

Comment: O método faz exatamente o que se pede. Repetir até que o usuário digite uma opção válida; nesse caso então ele sai.

Comment: @Articuno eu coloquei todo o método conforme solicitado..Repare que quando chamo o método menuImprimir(), aparece uma mensagem e armazena um valor na variavel menuImprimir, eu digito a opção invalida 3x e as 3 vezes ele entra no while e chama o metodo menuImprimir() de novo, na 4ºx eu digito o certo, ele pula o while e entra no switch.
Então se eu digitei o 2, ele deveria aparecer a mensagem 2 finalizar o metodo. 
Só que ele aparece a mensagem e volta para comparar o while de novo, passa do while pq a opção digitado é 2, imprimi de novo e volta, repetindo esse processo por mais 2x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou adivinhar o que o método `getMenu` faz:

- escreve as opções
- pede para o usuário digitar um número
- le e retorna o número digitado

Então, toda vez que for chamado, irá requerer um novo digito. Nessa linha `while(getMenu() < 0 || getMenu() > 1)` irá pedir o digito pela primeira vez e comparar ele com zero. Se não for menor, irá pedir um **segundo digito** para comparar com 1. E, dentro do loop, o método é chamado pela **terceira** vez. Com certeza não é o que quer fazer...

A resposta da primeira chamada deve ser armazenada em uma variável para então o conteúdo dessa ser comparada, ou seja, o método é chamado apenas uma vez... somente sendo chamado novamente quando um novo valor for neessário.

Exemplo, muito simplificado (*usando a estrutura do código da pergunta*):

```
int menu = getMenu();
while (menu < 0 || menu > 1) {
    System.out.println(MENSAGEM_ERRO);
    if (menu == 0) {
        ...
        return;
    }
    if (menu == 1) {
        ...
        return;
    }
    ...

    menu = getMenu();
}
```

Uma estrutura um pouco melhor seria:

```
while (true) {
    int menu = getMenu();
    if (menu == 0) {
        ...
        return;
    }
    if (menu == 1) {
        ...
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(MENSAGEM_ERRO);
}
```

(um pouco) Mais 'avançado' :

```
int menu;
while ((menu = getMenu()) < 0 || menu > 1) {
    System.out.println(MENSAGEM_ERRO);
}
switch (menu) {
    case 0:
        ...
        break;
    case 1:
        ...
        break;
    default: throw IllegalArgumentException("Error menu: " + menu);
}
```

Outra opção, melhor (IMHO): o método `getMenu` faz o teste do valor fornecido, somente retornando valores válidos...

Comment: Carlos, 
Eu aproveitei apenas a parte do switch, não usei o while pq cairia em loop infinito...

Eu tinha esquecido do switch... Poderia usar o default para chamar o menu de novo caso desse o erro..Vlw

Comment: Carlos, eu achei que tinha dado certo.. Mas não deu .. ¬¬

Comment: O é basicamente a mesma validação, fiz 2 validações um para o Menu de impressão e outro o Menu principal. Usei a mesma estrutura. 
Mas eu consegui achar o erro. 
Eu usei o switch usando case1 e case 2 e o final usei apenas 1 if. Obrigado pela ajuda!